# How to fix problems between google fonts and slow website speed?

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, google-fonts

My website has a low speed problm (I've attached the GTmetrix result)
So, I added following codes in css, head and WP Rocket, but GTmetrix still shows the same google font issues.
Would you please let me know how to fix this problem?

CSS:

```
html, body, button, input, select, textarea, textfield {
font-size: 100%;
font-family: "Gothic A1", Sans-serif;
font-display: swap;
}
```

Head:

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="preload" href="$CSS&display=swap" type="text/css" as="style" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="$CSS&display=swap" media="print" onload="this.media='all'" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="googlewebfonturl&display=swap">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet';"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="all.css"  media="all" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="desktop.css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)">
```

WP Rocket:
[image]

GTmetrix:
[image]

Thank you.